# OpenSIPS fork=yes required when listening on multiple ports?

Tags: kamailio, opensips, openser

If I set OpenSIPS to listen on multiple ports on the same IP, do I need to set fork=yes or is that an old option no longer needed? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[The *fork=* option was removed in OpenSIPS 2.2](https://www.opensips.org/Documentation/Script-CoreParameters-2-2#toc59)

Answer (score 0):

The parameter 'listen' can be set multiple times in the same configuration file. Doing so will instruct opensips to listen on all protocol:addresses:ports specified.

Example: listen to UDP ports 5060 and 5070 on the (fake) address 10.10.10.10

```
listen = udp:10.10.10.10:5060
listen = udp:10.10.10.10:5070
```

You can even mix different protocols and interface like:

```
listen = udp:eth0:5080
listen = tcp:eth1:5090
```

Cheers.